# How Can I use my Metamask accouns to deploy a contract using Truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, metamask, ropsten

I have the full geth node on my machine and want to deploy my smart contract on ropsten using truffle.

In truffle.js fileI have connected to the node as the following:

```
ropsten: {

 host: "Localhost",     // Localhost (default: none)
 port: 8545 ,           // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
 network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
 // from: "",      // Ropsten's id
  // gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
  // confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  // timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  // skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```

In the terminal, I run the node by the following command:

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=1048 --ropsten --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 console
```

How can I use the funds that in my accounts in Metamask to deploy the contract on truffle?

When I check my accounts balances in geth console, it returns 0 where it has some ether in Metamask Chorome extension

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to deploy your contracts on ropsten network or on your own private geth node.?
If you want to deploy to ropsten you can simply use [infura's](https://infura.io/) API.

Also If you are trying to deploy from your metamask account.

- First you need to get your metamask seedphrase from somewhere in metamask's setting
- Then use [@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) package on truffle-config.js to deploy from your metamask account

How? here is the truffle-config.js file below

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const mnemonic = <your mnemonic from metamask>
ropsten: {
  provider: function () {
    return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<your infura key>")
  },
  network_id: 3, // Ropsten's id
  gas: 7000000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
  confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  skipDryRun: true // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```

PS: make sure that you have deposited some ether in your first account of metamask.

Note: you need to store your mnemonic somewhere safe in config or .env file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but infura does not support events. My front end is python with web3.py and it can not listen to many events so for this I have deownloded a full node. I want to deploy on ropsten but without using Infura and instead use the node on my machine

Comment: I did all you mention in your answer but if I would like to listen to more than one events, it says: "RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message"

Comment: Have you used websocket enpoint of your node to listen/subscribe to contract events? If so, there shouldnt be any problem

Comment: yes, my code look like 
PROVIDER = "wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/f5000000000000"
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(PROVIDER))
If I run it for more than one event filter, this error raise: RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

Comment: Okay, then there should be some bug on your code. 
- make sure that your code is running asynchronously.
- make sure you have instantiated your contract properly and contract exist on blockchaini.e contract-address
- make sure that contract have the event
- on your contract check your event parameters are indexed if you are filtering based on event topics
-

Comment: sorry what do you mean "running asynchronously"? I am running every listener in a thread. Look section “Running the event loop in a separate thread” https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html

Comment: Try referring this to listen for contrct events- https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#events

Comment: Sorry for my many questions. How can I get every trx done in the network to get its receipt and put it in a loop and then get its log and listen to the events there.What I understood that I need a loop to check frequently if there is any event triggered and then listen to it

Comment: If you need a real time listener you can luse a WebSocket connectionlike:

[https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#asynchronous-filter-polling]

but if you want all the transactions of past you can use:
`web3.eth.getLogs()` to querry past block range